# Unknown small library (ex. webhdfs-java-client) in maven not found

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am trying to implement a little service in Scala using Maven to manage dependencies and I would like to add webhdfs-java-client that I have found at https://github.com/wdavidw/webhdfs-java-client

I have added to pom.xml following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zxs</groupId>
    <artifactId>webhdfs-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It does not work, as I have expected. Does anyone could give me an advice if there exists some catalog of maven repositories (something like pip for Python)? And what can I possibly do if I'll not find this library in the catalog? Is it possible to somehow add it to maven manually?

Comment: The central maven repository is http://search.maven.org , but I can't seem to find any reference to it. Are you sure it's distributed through maven?

Comment: I'm not sure. If not, then what kind of options do I have? Build it locally and append it to maven locally?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia central maven repository is just one of the many repos out there (cloudera, clojars just to name a few).

Comment: @ziky90 You are right. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In maven world you can *install* this dependency locally and resolution will be done via local cache (the one that usually resides in ~/.m2). Steps are as simple as `mvn clean install` in that repo. Having said this, it wouldn't resolve problem for your users (transitive dependencies, you know), which is why you likely need to publish that dependency somewhere (or ask library author whether it's published somewhere).

SBT, which is scala's de-facto build tool allows you to depend on other sbt flavored projects simply by referencing their git repository, but sadly, maven has no such feature.